No sound (except wired headphones) after upgrading Ubuntu-MATE 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS (Asus ROG laptop)
I'm running Ubuntu-MATE on an Asus ROG laptop. I have had trouble with sound before but fixed it using the following:

add line options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook to the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and reboot (source)
sudoedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
and add these before the [Element PCM] block: (source)

[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore

However, I haven't been able to get any sound out of the built-in speakers since I upgraded to 24.04 LTS this morning. I can get sound out of wired headphones plugged into the jack.
Things I've tried:

reverting to kernel 6.8.0-35
commenting that line out of alsa-base.conf
changing the model= option to various things found on the web

Sound preferences shows two devices under "Hardware":

Built-in Audio, 1 Output / 1 Input, Analog Stero Duplex
TU106 High Definition Audio Controller, Disabled, Pro Audio

I think the microphone is working because the bars move when I clap my hands over the laptop.
